# How to implement a counter after finding highest value and accessing a value in 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been having issues trying to implement a counter for 3 players for a game based on user-inputted scores as well as trying to access the name of that player.

```
void winner(const string NAMES[NUM], const int SCORES[DAYS][NUM]) {
    int player1, player2, player;
    string winner
    for (int row = 0; row < DAYS; row++) {
        int max = SCORES[row][0];
        for (int col = 1; col < NUM; col++) {
            if (SCORES[row][col] > max) {
                max = SCORES[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code already is able to find the highest values in a column. My goal is to try to find out, in a game of 7 days and 3 players, who has the overall highest score. However, I'm having trouble trying to implement a counter for a player after finding out they have the highest score in a set column as well as trying to find the name of the player.

Comment: "I'm having trouble trying to implement a counter for a player" --> you could post your troublesome code.

Answer (score 0):

Using your structure, you might do something like:

```
void winner(const string NAMES[NUM], const int SCORES[DAYS][NUM]) {
    int best_scores[NUM]{};

    for (int p = 0; p != NUM; ++p) {
        for (int day = 0; day != DAYS; ++day) {
            best_scores[p] = std::max(best_scores[p], SCORES[day][p]);
        }
    }
    auto best_player = std::distance(std::begin(best_scores), std::max_element(std::begin(best_scores), std::end(best_scores));

    std::cout << "winner is " << NAMES[best_player] << " with score " << best_scores[best_player] << std::endl;
}
```

I suggest to create struct to group names and scores.

```
struct Player
{
    std::string name;
    std::array<int, DAYS> scores: // or int scores[DAYS]; 

    int best_score() const { return *std::max_element(scores.begin(), scores.end());}
};
```

and then

```
void winner(const Player (&player)[NUM]) {
    auto compare = [](const Player& lhs, const Player& rhs) {
        return lhs.best_score() < rhs.best_score();
    };

    const Player& best = *std::max_element(std::begin(players), std::end(players), compare);

    std::cout << "winner is " << best.name << " with score " << best.best_score() << std::endl;
}
```